# ViewGroup causing StackOverflow at dispatchDraw

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view, stack-overflow

I have a class overriding ViewGroup. Here's my implementation of dispatchDraw:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

    mViewBehind.drawShadow(mContent, canvas);
    mViewBehind.drawFade(mContent, canvas, getPercentOpen());
    mViewBehind.drawSelector(mContent, canvas, getPercentOpen());
}
```

However, sometimes I'm getting this StackOverflowError:

```
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:365)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4225)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1586)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.widget.GridView.dispatchDraw(GridView.java:1948)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2967)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1423)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at com.ui.library.slidingmenu2.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:931)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at com.ui.library.slidingmenu2.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:931)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at com.ui.library.slidingmenu2.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:931)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1921)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1528)
01-25 09:20:38.569: E/AndroidRuntime(15480):    at android.view.Vie
```

The stack trace shows `com.ui.library.slidingmenu2.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:931)` (Which is `super.dispatchDraw(canvas)`) is getting called at least 4 times.

The exception only happens when I return to a certain activity which contains a ViewPager whose first Fragment contains a GridView, and only some times.

(BTW, what is a `BoringLayout` anyway?)

Comment: Hi,I'm facing same issue.Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There must be too many layers, try to reduce your layout layer.

Answer (score 0):

A BoringLayout is a very simple Layout implementation for text that fits on a single line and is all left-to-right characters.

Comment: seems you got the lines from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/BoringLayout.html